# Add constraints in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

Anybody can you give me suggestions to add constraint to this Layout?

This is my layout screenshot :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FBnJ.png]

I try many times but it's not work for me to auto layout for all device screen .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click in the IB first you click a view ,then resolve auto layout issues ,then click reset to suggested constant in the All Views section